# Syntax Error in UPDATE statement in VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, syntax, oledb

I have the following query and I can for love nor money work out where the error is in my `UPDATE` statement? I only started playing with this last week so I'm on a big learning curve!

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Declerations For Calling on
    Dim AnimalHouse As String
    AnimalHouse = "TestText"
    Dim AddressForAssingment As Integer
    AddressForAssingment = 1
    Dim IDCheckAssignment As Integer
    IDCheckAssignment = 1
    Dim CommandText As String = _
        "UPDATE IOInformation.Description = @animalHouse, WHERE ID_number = @addrForAssn AND ID_Check = @Id;"

    'Connection Information 
    Dim myConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + ProjectDirectory.Text)
    Dim myCommand As New OleDbCommand(CommandText)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@animalHouse", AnimalHouse)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addrForAssn", AddressForAssingment)
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", IDCheckAssignment)

    myCommand.Connection = myConnection
    myConnection.Open()
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myConnection.Close()


End Sub
```

Comment: Try change your command text to: `UPDATE IOInformation SET Description = @animalHouse WHERE ID_number = @addrForAssn AND ID_Check = @Id;`

Comment: It is a simple typo in your query. Remove the comma before the WHERE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of errors in your syntax.

The correct syntax for an UPDATE query is

```
UPDATE table SET field1=value1, field2=value2, ...... WHERE keyfield=value
```

so you should write

```
Dim CommandText As String = _
    "UPDATE IOInformation SET Description = @animalHouse " & 
    "WHERE ID_number = @addrForAssn AND ID_Check = @Id;"
```

Separate the table name from the field name, add a SET before the first fieldname and remove the comma before the WHERE

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following syntax for update `UPDATA tablename SET collumnName='value', columnname1='adsf' WHERE ...`, no ',' before where. `UPDATE IOInformation SET Description = ... WHERE ID_number = ... AND ID_Check = ...;`

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE IOInformation
SET Description = @animalHouse
WHERE  ID_number        = @addrForAssn
       AND ID_Check     = @Id
```

Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå & Steve are correct in the comments below your question